# Typing a generic object as input

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm creating a function that gets in input an object, does some computations and returns another object.
What the function exactly does is not important. The important thing is the format of the input and output objects.

Indeed the input object must contain a key/value named `color` of type `string`. The output will be another object equals to the input one but with some properties more.

How can I typing that?

I thought something like that but I don't know if it is the right way or if exists better solutions.
In particular, I don't like `any`. Is `&` the right operator? Is that a case where to use `extends`? And how?

```
type Input = any & {color: string}
type Outout = Input & { newColor: string }

function doSomething(value: Input) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: `any` just overrides whatever you're doing. Just remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function doSomethingM<T extends { color: string }>(value: T): T & { newColor: string } {
    return;
}
```

More generic:

```
type Input = { color: string }
type Output<T> = T & { newColor: string }

function doSomethingM<T extends Input>(value: T): Output<T> {
    return;
}
```